# VB.NET create avi from matrix

Tags: vb.net, video, avi

I have multiple grayscale pictures represented as matrices with rgb value. Since it's grayscale, each field in matrix is filled with single number.

How to create video out of those pictures? One way would be to export matrices as .jpg and then make video, but that is too slow.

it is grayscale so rgb value is only one number.

for example if matrix will be

2 12 255

5 10 222

8 22 200

then i need to create avi 3x3 pixels.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend checking out the Code Project article: [A Simple C# Wrapper for the AviFile Library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7388/A-Simple-C-Wrapper-for-the-AviFile-Library). Although it's targeted at C#, it should be easy to apply to VB.Net too.